# Questions about social groups for くれる、あげる

Tags: giving-and-receiving

I wanted to know how you would use くれる、あげる when it comes to situations like:

- The speaker is saying "He gives corrections to everyone" where both of the people he is mentioning isn't a part of his うち would I say

> 彼はみんなに修正をあげる

Other than that if I were going to say "If you want me to forgive youー" would I say, like the speaker is speaking but it's in he viewpoint of the person who wants forgiveness

> あなたは僕に許してもらいたいのならー

Comment: What does it mean to "give corrections" to people?

Comment: @istrasci Oh my bad I meant something like "he corrects people", sorry English isn't my first language.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer that you are asking for, but I would like to point out that 彼はみんなに修正をあげる does not work, not because of incorrect social situation but because the direct translation of "give corrections" as 修正をあげる somehow does not work in the Japanese language. I would use:

- (person/document)の誤【あやま】りを修正する
- (person/document)の間違いを修正する
- (document)に修正を加える

As for the second question,

> あなたは僕に許してもらいたいのなら

First of all, は cannot be used as a subject marker in subordinate clauses (See [は vs が in 私は言うように書いてください。](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43517/%e3%81%af-vs-%e3%81%8c-in-%e7%a7%81%e3%81%af%e8%a8%80%e3%81%86%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab%e6%9b%b8%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84) ) for more details. Hence「あなた**が**僕に許してもらいたいのなら」.

However, using pronouns is awkward here in the fist place. It is best to use 「許してもらいたいのなら」, without either of the two pronouns you wrote.